# Google Identity Toolkit and API keys

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, google-identity-toolkit

I'm really confused about all these proceeds...

I need to build a REST API, where the user needs to be authenticated.

As a platform, I use Google App Engine with Go SDK.

I read an article about Google Identity Toolkit, and I was impressed to know what the tool can accomplish, even if I don't get all.

I wish to know if I can generate API keys through the Identity's service. I'm also open to other proposal to solve my problem...

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "authenticate an user without prompt"?

Comment: Without display a form. I imagine an API where I can POST the login/password or a key

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand the question. The result of an Identity Toolkit sign in is an ID Token that can be validated at your REST API endpoints. Is this what you mean by API key?